# Postgresql 9.2 execute pg_dump command issue

Tags: postgresql, post

I need to back up the command postgres database.

I can execute the command successfully but command want to enter the password for the execution So what should I do to avoid the entering password.

Below are the command:

```
pg_dump -i -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -F c -b -v C:\PostgreSQL\PostgreSQL\bin\Data.backup" DB_NAME
```

Please suggest me what should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the `pg_hba.conf` in your `PostgreSQL Server`, If your using `pgAdmin` then go to Tools > Server Configuration ->ph_hba.conf

and change `ticked` Type's Method to `trust`

[image]

and restart `PostgreSQL server`

---

I strongly recommend you to use `MD5`

Quoted from [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-pgdump.html)

> -w
>   --no-password Never issue a password prompt. If the server requires password authentication and a password is not available by other means
>   such as a .pgpass file, the connection attempt will fail. This option
>   can be useful in batch jobs and scripts where no user is present to
>   enter a password.
>
> -W
>   --password Force pg_dump to prompt for a password before connecting to a database.
>
> This option is never essential, since pg_dump will automatically
>   prompt for a password if the server demands password authentication.
>   However, pg_dump will waste a connection attempt finding out that the
>   server wants a password. In some cases it is worth typing -W to avoid
>   the extra connection attempt.

Comment: The `-W yourPassword` is definitely incorrect. `pg_dump` doesn't accept a password in its arguments and `-W` doesn't help in automated passwordless connections.

Answer (score 0):

Better than blindly allowing the entire world to access your database is to set up a [pgpass file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/libpq-pgpass.html).

This is a simple text file that you should make sure is only readable by your user account. Then, just fill in the host/port/db/user/password details and psql and pg_dump etc. will automatically use it instead of prompting you.

**NOTE** - if other people can read this file then they can see your password. So make sure they can't.